# Some times there is Traceback, and sometime there is not in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax-error

I was messing around in the Python Interpreter, and I realized one strange thing. Interpreter Session:

```
>>> some_var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'some_var' is not defined
>>> "
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    "
     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

The first error I get because `some_var` is not defined, and the second error because its invalid syntax.

In the first one I get `Traceback (most recent call last):`, but in the second one I don't. Why is this?

Comment: A `SyntaxError` causes your code to fail to compile (since it's invalid syntax), it doesn't even get run which is why there is no traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a `Traceback` when the code is successfully executed/compiled, and when you don't get a `Traceback`, it isn't successfully compiled.

In the example, it tries to find `some_var`, but it doesn't exist, but it is still successfully compiled, so it gives a `Traceback`. But since `"` is not compiled successfully so there is no `Traceback`.